# ReactJS v4 routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, buttonclick

i was wondering how is it possible to change component in Onclick event so far ive came across these and none of them works

1)`this.props.history.push('/')`

which causes this error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

2)`this.context.router.history.push('/')`

which causes this error:Cannot read property 'history' of undefined

3)`this.context.history.push('/')`

which causes this error:Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

4)`using BrowserRouter`

which as it seems is not available in react v4 so this is not a solution

5)`creating new instance of sth with the name of hash history and then using that object push method`

which causes sth like myurl.com/#/navigatelink, and that # in url ruins everything

6) `using window.location.href`

which causes to refresh and reload the page which is undesired

7)`creating new instance of BrowserHistory from history/createBrowserHistory`

which works fine in url of my browser and expected url appears but the component wont change and this time i have to manually press f5 and refresh the page

so can you please tell me how im supposed to navigate to other page or component with onclick event without refreshing the page in react v4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import `createHistory` from the [`history`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) package separately and create your own `history` object instance that you pass to the `Router` component, which you can use anywhere you see fit in your app.

**Example**

```js
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

const history = createHistory();

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <main>
        <Router history={history}>
          <button onClick={() => history.push('/')}> Click me </button>
          {/* ... */}
        </Router>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you used the `withRouter` HOC to make sure the react router props are actually being passed down to your component? It sounds like that isn't happening. Log out the props directly below the routes and make sure you pass the props down as necessary. You could also use the `withRouter` HOC on the component you want the props in and it'll inject them.